count continuous enrollment in claims data
I need to count number of patients with continuous enrollment after indexdt by month in claims data in SAS.
Below is my data structure.

startdt is the starting date of insurance coverage and
enddt is the end date of insurance coverage.

If there a gap between two start dates, the patient is categorized no continuous enrollment
(continuous_enroll=0), otherwise has continuous enrollment
(continuous_enroll=1).
data input;
  input ID $1. startdt:mmddyy10. enddt:mmddyy10. indexdt :mmddyy10. continuous_enroll;
  format startdt date9. enddt date9. indexdt date9. ;
  datalines;
1  1/1/2020 1/31/2020 3/12/2020 .
1  2/1/2020 2/28/2020 3/12/2020 1
1  3/1/2020 3/31/2020 3/12/2020 1
1  5/1/2020 5/31/2020 3/12/2020 0
2  8/1/2019 8/31/2019 3/16/2020 .
2  3/1/2020 3/31/2020 3/16/2020 0
3  4/1/2020 4/30/2020 4/13/2020 .
3  5/1/2020 5/31/2020 4/13/2020 1
3  8/1/2020 8/31/2020 4/13/2020 0
3  9/1/2020 9/31/2020 4/13/2020 1

;
run;


I need to count
the number of unique patients with continuous enrollment 1 month after index date.

The number of unique patients with continuous enrollment 2 month after index date.

The number of unique patients with continuous enrollment 3 month after index date.
....
All the way up to 12 months.


Let me know if my question is not clear. Thank you for your help!

What did you try?  Did you check previous SO questions?  Check out these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsas%5D+enrollment

What is the answer for totals using the example data.
